# How to manage stale websocket connections

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, ping, debouncing

Using Python Websockets [1] to manage a set of server-side websocket connections from browser. They must be registered and maintained.

Problem: when User disconnects a stale connection remains present in the registry. Also, if user refreshes browser (1, 2, 17, or n times), or a reconnect script is present, more invalid connections are registered. This creates a registry full of stale connections.

The docs address this issue as follows:

> As shown in the synchronization example above, if you need to maintain
> a list of currently connected clients, you must register them when
> they connect and unregister them when they disconnect.

How are stale connections properly identified and removed? Is some sort of ping/pong scheme required?

I did find the code in [2], but it goes back to 2018. Is this obsolete, or has this issue since been addressed?

Ref:

1. https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html
2. https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/issues/414

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes a ping/pong scheme is used to ensure a connection. TCP uses something similar with [`keep-alive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive). Send a ping every X seconds and if the client misses N times, then it's safe to assume the client connection is dead and can be removed. The link #2 you provided is essentially the gist of how you would do implement a keep-alive. Here is an example using [`autobahn`](https://nicolovaligi.com/automatic-reconnection-websockets-autobahn.html), which has a lot of quality of life features I have not seen in other frameworks.

I could be wrong, but I thought websockets send some sort of a "disconnect" signal when you refresh the browser, so you should be able to kill connections that way. I haven't worked with websockets in a few years, but I recommend making your UI a single page app and "dissuade" users from refreshing. Not always though.